# Xcode: My user location doesn't show the first time I run the simulation but the second time it does

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Whenever I first open up the project and hit build and run the first time the app won't focus on the current user location. But if I stop the simulation and build it again and run it, it will then focus on the user location like I want it to. I can't figure out why it does this, is it something wrong with the simulator or is something wrong with my code?

```
super viewDidLoad];
self.mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
self.mapview.delegate = self;
[self.mapview setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
```

Comment: Have you tried it on real device as well?

Comment: I haven't I'm new to Xcode and the mac, just bought one a few days ago, so I'm not sure how to put it on my device yet. I'll look into doing that first and update after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Debug->Location Service ?
[try this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html)

Answer (score 0):

For now move `self.mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;` to the last line. This could do what you expect.